# Multiple Contexts in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For my online shop I need to use 3 React Contexts:

- Authentication Context which checks is User authenticated, then saves
  boolean isAuth in state, and has login and logout functions.
- Favorite Products Context
- Shopping Cart Context

Also *Favorite Products context* and *Shopping Cart context* need to use *Authentication Context*, because un-authenticated user is able to add products to *Shopping Cart* and then be able to signup after clicking "Check out".

Other pages and components also need to has access to these contexts.

The reason to use Authentication context in Shopping Cart context is that cart is stored in database if user is authenticated and in cookies (or state) if user is not authenticated

The problem is that `Context Consumer` is available only in `render()` but I need to use context in *lifecycle functions* such as `ComponentDidMount()` and my own functions.

Recently I found "*with-context*" npm-library, and I think it can solve the problem.

What is the proper way to *combine* all these context?

Comment: The reason to use Authentication context in Shopping Cart context is that cart is stored in database if user is authenticated and in cookies (or state) if user is not authenticated

Comment: Take a look at this GitHub issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12397. It has a number of code examples of how to use the Context API; long story short, you should be using an HOC approach, i.e. executing your context consumer in a render and passing the appropriate data down to the component as a prop.

Answer (score -2):

you need something like this:

```
class B{

}

const A = props => (
    <Consumer>
        {context => <B {...props} context={context} />}
    </Consumer>
);

export default A;
```

here all lifecycle methods of class B will access the context